# What are the commonly accepted loading patterns in data intensive iOS apps these days?

Tags: ios, design-patterns, afnetworking, loading, strategy-pattern

So I have an app with a bunch of loading screens, all remain under 5 seconds, but compared to apps like Instagram, Yik Yak, FB, Twitter....it's a worlds difference. I don't I see a loading dialog beyond the initial splash no matter where in the app I go initially in any of these apps. Is there a commonly accepted pattern to loading data into an app beyond the initial screen a user lands on on open?

Are they doing requests in the background? Are they doing one giant request initially thats considered acceptable if you provide a user with a splash screen?

Answer (score 2):

Usually loading of data that may take longer  is done on a background thread. With GCD that is quite easy to do.

Yet you have to make the app active in some way, users may want to start pressing buttons already. Thus, caching the data between starts and showing "old" data in the beginning is good to keep the user happy.

Splitting requests up or doing one large requests depends a lot on the type of data and on the backend as well.

And the "problem" exists not only on iOS, also on desktop systems one have to consider how to load data. So a quite common problem.